# Directed Graph: How to find the longest path of Node A to N Considering the ff code:

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, graph

I have considered using **DFS** for tracking the vertex for each edges present to find the **longest path** but the problem is it gives only the **L input** to it and the edge corresponding to it. I want to find the longest path traversed by these vertices as a alphabetically nondecreasing string and if the string playes indefenitely it outputs infinite. Here is my initial working code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def DFS(G,v,seen=None, path=None):
    if seen is None: seen = []
    if path is None: path = [v]

    seen.append(v)

    paths =[]
    for i in G[v]:
        if i not in seen:
            i_path = path + [i]
            paths.append(tuple(i_path))
            paths.extend(DFS(G, i, seen[:], i_path))

    return paths

t = int(input())
i,j = 1,0
graph = defaultdict(list)
while i < t:
    n, a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    while j < a:
        n1,n2,l = input().split()
        graph[l].append(n1)
        graph[l].append(n2)
        j+= 1
    print(graph)
    print(DFS(graph, 'A'))
    i+=1
```

i want to know where i did wrong or maybe i missed something essential since the given output for the sample input is:

```
    INPUT:
        1 // test case
        5 7 // n, a
        2 3 B
        3 1 E
        1 2 A
        1 2 R
        2 4 D
        3 5 E
        4 3 D
        Expected : ADDER
        ACTUAL: D, D
```